# Schedule SP in SQL Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, job-scheduling, ssms-2014

I have an stored procedure which run an SSIS package.

Below is the script

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MRA
AS
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'CNP_FORMAT.dtsx',
@execution_id= @execution_id OUTPUT,
@folder_name=N'MRA',
  @project_name=N'CNP_FORMAT',
@use32bitruntime=False,
  @reference_id=Null
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

> The script run correctly in sql server where targeted table are uploaded correctly.
>   I have schedule above script in SQL Agent.
>   Schedule Job runs without errors but targeted table NOT uploaded.
>
> Means the schedule job in SQL Agent did not run the ssis package!
>
> I'm currently stuck with this issue and don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the complication of using a stored procedure? Create a job that executes the package directly as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-ver15). The same link also mentions trouble-shooting steps. Did you ask your DBA for help?

Comment: The script in you question creates a stored procedure but does not run the proc. You need to run the stored proc with T-SQL step ``EXEC dbo.MRA`;`. That said, you don't need to encapsulate the SSIS package execution in a proc unless you have special needs that are not evident here.

Comment: Dup on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4abb0285-3afb-4b0a-b760-74acfe45e675/schedule-sp-in-sql-agent?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: @SMor I have already tried your mentionned step 
getting errors : Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER2. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.5000.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added the script in the step part of the scheduler EXEC dbo.MRA; still its not working  accordingly.

Comment: That "error" isn't an error about @KAN . Using a step to execute the package is the right choice; using an SP to do so it the wrong choice.